# How to free appsrc?

Tags: c++, linux, gstreamer

I have used **appsrc** element to inject data from application into pipeline. I wanna free **appsrc (GstAppSrc)** by myself, but i don't know how to do that. Please help me, thank so much!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Answer (score 1):

If you added it to the pipeline, it will be freed when pipeline is deleted. If you want to do it earlier, you can just remove it from pipeline (gst_bin_remove). I assumed you have no additional references to your appsrc.